# Security group created by Terraform has no rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-aws

I am now studying Terraform and wrote a simple script to create some AWS resources.

From my script, it can create a VPC with a subnet, and an instance attached a security group. All of them are newly created by the terraform script. When I run terraform plan or terraform apply, no error or warning have shown and successfully created. However, when I check the those newly created resources on AWS console, I found that the security group has created but no rules attached.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Following is my terraform script.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.AWS_REGION
  access_key = var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_key = var.AWS_SECRET_KEY
}

data "aws_ami" "amazon-2" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = [ "amazon" ]

  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = [ "amzn2-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-ebs" ]
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "generate_keypair" {
  key_name = var.key_name
  public_key = var.public_key
  tags = var.default_tags
}

resource "aws_vpc" "study" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/20"
  tags = var.default_tags
}

resource "aws_subnet" "study-public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.study.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/26"
  tags = var.default_tags
}

resource "aws_security_group" "public-instance" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.study.id
  name = "public-instance"
  description = "Group for public instance"
  tags = var.default_tags

  ingress {
    description = "Port 80 ingress"
    from_port = 80
    to_port = 80
    protocol = "tcp"
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Port 22 ingress"
    from_port = 22
    to_port = 22
    protocol = "ssh"
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "all"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "linux" {
  ami = data.aws_ami.amazon-2.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  key_name = aws_key_pair.generate_keypair.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.public-instance.id ]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.study-public.id
  tags = var.default_tags
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are looking for: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify at least any one of the rule destination like CIDR block, a security group ID or a prefix list.

Below code snippet works for you. I have used `cidr_blocks` in this case.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "public-instance" {
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.study.id
  name        = "public-instance"
  description = "Group for public instance"

  ingress {
    description = "Port 80 ingress"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Port 22 ingress"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "all"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `cidr_blocks = ["<your ip cidr>"]` and change `protocol = "tcp"`

```
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "all"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```